# How do you push to a gitlab repo using a gitlab-ci job?

Tags: git, python-2.7, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to GitLab CI/CD jobs, but I'm trying to set up a Python script that when pushed to GitLab, triggers the CI/CD job to run it, and call an internal function that pushes to GitLab again provided that certain criteria are met. So, for example, suppose I have the following:

```
def hasFileInDirectory():
    # checks if the current directory has at least 1 other file in it
    if (1 or more files exist):
        print 'Great! You have enough files!';
    else:
        print 'Oh no! You need more files! Let me create one!';
        createFile('missingFile'+str(random.randint(0,1000000)+'.txt');
        os.system('git add -A');
        os.system('git commit -m "Automatically added new file..."');
        os.system('git push origin HEAD:master --force');
```

This function seems to run perfectly fine if I run it myself from the command line, however, it seems to not be able to run in the GitLab CI/CD job. The output I am getting is:

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxx@gitlab.com/path_to/my_repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

This error occurs when I call `git push` so I was wondering what I could do to fix this. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push from gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472250/cannot-push-from-gitlab-ci-yml)

Answer (score 21):

A GitLab CI runner cannot yet push to a repo: there is a [proposal in progress here](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3559).

In the meantime, you can [use an SSH URL](https://nicolaw.uk/GitLabCiPushingWrites), with:

- An SSH private key is defined as a secret variable through the Settings > CI/CD Pipelines web interface in GitLab, and
- the public part of the SSH key is stored as a deployment key Settings > Repository > Deploy Keys section of the same web UI.

Or, as [mentioned here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-push-from-a-project-to-another/11038/3), you can use a “personal access token” in Settings of your profile.

> I created a token with scope api and configure in my pipeline.
> Open the project in gitlab console, go to Settings > CI/CD > Secret variables, create a variable with value the key (generated in profile).
> I replace “${CI_JOB_TOKEN}” to my variable “${VAR01}”.

With a gitlab-ci.yml

> ```
> script:
> ```

```
   - url_host=`git remote get-url origin | sed -e "s/https:\/\/gitlab-ci-token:.*@//g"`
   - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_TAG_UPLOAD_TOKEN}@${url_host}"
```

`CI_TAG_UPLOAD_TOKEN` is the Secret variable

Comment: Both solutions have drawbacks. "ssh url" can't be used in some environments, where only http access is possible. And "personal access token" is personal - when CI job wants to change something in repository - it should be done not from some predefined user account, but from the one, who started a job.

Comment: @Ezh So using a deploy token (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/deploy_tokens/) instead of a user token? That should work. and match your criteria.

Comment: @VonC deploy tokens can not be used to write to the repository. Use can use them to read the repository or read/write the registry.

Comment: @MartinŽid OK, no deploy token then.

Answer (score 2):

The command we ended up using was:

```sh
git tag my-new-tag
git push --repo=git@YOUR_REPO_URL:YOUR_GROUP/YOUR_PROJECT.git --tags
```

By default we were getting:

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@YOUR_REPO_URL:YOUR_FORK/YOUR_PROJECT.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`
```

The reason is because the CI runner executes git commands using the HTTPS protocol with a token that does not support push as stated by @VonC.

We have configured our runner to share a volume to the `/root/.ssh` directory. So using the `git` protocol and a proper `ssh` configuration we are able to push git commands using the Gitlab CI runner.

### Edit

The `gitlab` runner is exectuded as follows (I removed useless parameters for the purpose of clarity)

```
docker exec -it gitlab-runner.service gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --name `hostname` \
  --url "some-gitlab-url" \
  ...
  --executor "docker" \
  --limit "1" \
  --docker-image "debian" \
  --docker-volumes "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" \
  --docker-volumes "/fs1/runner/builds:/builds" \
  --docker-volumes "/fs1/runner/cache:/cache" \
  --docker-volumes "/fs1/runner/profile:/root" \
```

So the `/root` directory is shared across all our runners. Therefore once configured properly with `/root/.ssh/` proper keys and those keys have the right to `push` to gitlab, it will work as described above.

Comment: Could you please detail the part "onfigured our runner to share a volume to the /root/.ssh directory". Was that in the ".gitlab-ci.yml'?

Comment: I've edited my response to give a little bit more details. Hopes this helps.

Comment: @jtheoof Are you saying that /root is already mounted across runners or that you had to change the way `docker exec` is launched (If so, then how)? The problem is that when using `gitlab-machines`, the runners are actually spawned as needed when the pipeline is started, so how would I configure the `/root/.ssh` then?

Comment: btw I do get `403` error code despite my token has all permissions possible.
there's absolutely no workaround to push via https?