# Add artifact to repository in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: git, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I have a multi-project pipeline. Project B depends on Project A. Inside Project B pipeline I am able to get my desired artifacts. Problem is that I am in the Runner's directory, The root path is `CI_PROJECT_DIR`, something like `buildMachine/builds/build#/0/groupname/project`.

I'm not sure what the path to the actually repository should be but it's not this. I need to take these files and add them to the gitlab repository..any advice?

Comment: You can access the files from Project B and you want to push them in Project A ?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution using a variation of the solution to this question..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465858/how-do-you-push-to-a-gitlab-repo-using-a-gitlab-ci-job

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you push to a gitlab repo using a gitlab-ci job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465858/how-do-you-push-to-a-gitlab-repo-using-a-gitlab-ci-job)

Comment: you linked the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to commit the artifacts to my Project B using a variation of this answers...

[How do you push to a gitlab repo using a gitlab-ci job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465858/how-do-you-push-to-a-gitlab-repo-using-a-gitlab-ci-job)