# GitLab runner, error on push whereas same thing works on git bash or python from a console

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-push, gitpython

### Context

We're trying to do a GitLab runner job that, on a certain tag, modifies a version header file and add a release branch/tag to this changeset.

The GitLab runner server is on my machine, launched as a service by my user (that is properly registered to our GitLab server).

The GitLab runner job basically launches a python script that uses gitpython to du the job, there are just a few changes in runner yml file (added `before_script` part to be able to have upload permission, got it from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344804/11159476), here is full `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

stages: [ build, publish, release ]

release_tag:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git config --global user.name ${GITLAB_USER_NAME}
    - git config --global user.email ${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}
  script:
    - python .\scripts\release_gitlab_runner.py
  only:
    # Trigger on specific regex...
    - /^Src_V[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
  except:
    # .. only for tags then except branches, see doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#regular-expressions): "Only the tag or branch name can be matched by a regular expression."
    - branches
```

Also added trick in the python URL when pushing (push with `user:personal_access_token@repo_URL` instead of default runner URL, got it from same answer as above, and token has been generated from company gitlab => user "Settings" => "Access Tokens" => "Add a personal access token" with all rights and never expiring), and here is, not the actual `scripts\release_gitlab_runner.py` python script but one simplified to have a git flow as much standard as possible for what we want (fetch all, create local branch with random name so that it does not exist, modify a file, stage, commit and finally push):

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

import uuid
import git
import sys
import os

# Since we are in <git root path>/scripts folder, git root path is this file's path parent path
GIT_ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
try:
    # Get user login and URL from GITLAB_USER_LOGIN and CI_REPOSITORY_URL gitlab environment variables
    gitlabUserLogin = os.environ["GITLAB_USER_LOGIN"]
    gitlabFullURL = os.environ["CI_REPOSITORY_URL"]
    # Push at "https://${GITLAB_USER_NAME}:${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.companyname.net/demo/demo.git")
    # generatedPersonalAccessToken has been generated with full rights from https://gitlab.companyname.net/profile/personal_access_tokens and set in a variable not seen here
    gitlabPushURL = "https://{}:{}@{}".format(gitlabUserLogin, generatedPersonalAccessToken, gitlabFullURL.split("@")[-1])
    print("gitlabFullURL is [{}]".format(gitlabFullURL))
    print("gitlabPushURL is [{}]".format(gitlabPushURL))

    branchName = str(uuid.uuid1())

    print("Build git.Repo object with [{}] root path".format(GIT_ROOT_PATH))
    repo = git.Repo(GIT_ROOT_PATH)

    print("Fetch all")
    repo.git.fetch("-a")

    print("Create new local branch [{}]".format(branchName))
    repo.git.checkout("-b", branchName)

    print("Modify file")
    versionFile = os.path.join(GIT_ROOT_PATH, "public", "include" , "Version.h")
    patchedVersionFileContent = ""
    with open(versionFile, 'r') as versionFileContent:
        patchedVersionFileContent = versionFileContent.read()
        patchedVersionFileContent = re.sub("#define VERSION_MAJOR 0", "#define VERSION_MAJOR {}".format(75145), patchedVersionFileContent)
    with open(versionFile, 'w') as versionFileContent:
        versionFileContent.write(patchedVersionFileContent)

    print("Stage file")
    repo.git.add("-u")

    print("Commit file")
    repo.git.commit("-m", "New version file in new branch {}".format(branchName))

    print("Push new branch [{}] remotely".format(branchName))
    # The error is at below line:
    repo.git.push(gitlabPushURL, "origin", branchName)

    sys.exit(0)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: {}".format(e))

    sys.exit(-1)
```

### Problem

Even with the trick to have rights, when we try to push from GitLab runner following error is raised:

```
Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git push https://user:token@gitlab.companyname.net/demo/repo.git origin 85a3fa6e-690a-11ea-a07d-e454e8696d31
  stderr: 'error: src refspec origin does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user:token@gitlab.companyname.net/demo/repo.git''
```

### What works

If I open a Git Bash, I successfully run manual commands:

```
git fetch -a
git checkout -b newBranch
vim public/include/Version.h
=> At this point file has been modified
git add -u
git commit -m "New version file in new branch"
git push origin newBranch
```

Here if we fetch all from elsewhere we can see newBranch with version file modifications

And same if we run script content (without URL modification) from a python command line (assuming all imports as in script have been performed):

```
GIT_ROOT_PATH = "E:\\path\\to\\workspace\\repo"
branchName = str(uuid.uuid1())
repo = git.Repo(GIT_ROOT_PATH)
repo.git.fetch("-a")
repo.git.checkout("-b", branchName)
versionFile = os.path.join(GIT_ROOT_PATH, "public", "include" , "Version.h")
patchedVersionFileContent = ""
with open(versionFile, 'r') as versionFileContent:
    patchedVersionFileContent = versionFileContent.read()
    patchedVersionFileContent = re.sub("#define VERSION_MAJOR 0", "#define VERSION_MAJOR {}".format(75145), patchedVersionFileContent)
with open(versionFile, 'w') as versionFileContent:
    versionFileContent.write(patchedVersionFileContent)
repo.git.add("-u")
repo.git.commit("-m", "New version file in new branch {}".format(branchName))
repo.git.push("origin", branchName)
```

### Conclusion

I can't find  what I do wrong when running from GitLab runner, is there something I'm missing ?

The only thing that I can see different when running from GitLab runner is that after fetch I can see I'm on a detached head (listing `repo.git.branch('-a').split('\n')` gives for example ['* (HEAD detached at 560976b)', 'branchName', 'remotes/origin/otherExistingBranch', ...]), but this should not be a problem since I create a new branch where to push, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git said that you used the wrong refspec. When you need to push in other remote you have to make it first `gitlab = repo.create_remote("gitlab", gitlabPushURL)` and push to it like `repo.push("gitlab", branchName)`.

Edit from @gluttony to not break on next git run with "remote already exists":

```py
remote_name = "gitlab"
if remote_name not in repo.remotes:
    repo.create_remote(remote_name, gitlabPushURL)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you literally made my day ! Since I'm a newbie at git and gitlab not sure I would have found this myself, not it a short term at least.