# Gitlab CI Pipeline "remote: You are not allowed to upload code."

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

From [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436314/gitlab-ci-get-list-of-files-changed-since-last-run) "Gitlab CI: get list of files changed since last run" I discovered that Gitlab CI has no variable that tracks the SHA-ID of the last commit on which the pipeline has been executed.

I'm trying to save the commit ID on a .txt that will be sourced by a shell script (variable is like `LAST_EXECUTED_SHA_ID=XYZ`). Now, after a pipeline execution I have to update such text file in order to track the current HEAD, changing `LAST_EXECUTED_SHA_ID` to `ZYX`. Now I have to: add the file, commit and push. I tried to do so using gitlab-runner both with a shell script and .gitlab-ci.yml file itself but I encounter several errors like "remote: You are not allowed to upload code."

Is there any way to fix this error? It seems like an ssh / auth token error or similar

Comment: Can't you tag the current commit every time the pipeline is run instead of storing it in a txt file? For the next pipeline, you delete the tag and recreate it on the future current HEAD. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is a more elegant solution and can be used instead of txt file handling. The problem about "remote: You are not allowed to upload code" still persists even with "git push --tags"

Comment: Solved added an ad-hoc auth token with more permissions that the standard CI auth token