# How to bump package.json version of project on GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I would like to bump the `package.json` *version* variable on every push:

- `0.1.0 => 0.1.1` (for example)

My project uses *Yarn* thus I stumbled across the following command:

- `yarn version --patch --no-git-tag-version`

This does indeed bump the version how I expect, but only affects the local cached `package.json` file and not the `package.json` file on the actual repository:

[image: updates cached package.json]

My question is therefore, **how can I bump the `package.json` *version* variable on the actual *GitLab* repository through CI/CD pipelines?**

Comment: You may need to use semantic versioning tasks in the pipeline

Comment: Please check this https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/auto-bump-apps-versions-and-releases-using-gitlab-pipeline-e32f1d7fa3ee

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it good, but you need to commit the new version. You can do it by keeping the tag and it will automatically be committed :

```
$ yarn version --patch
yarn version v1.22.5
info Current version: 0.1.0
info New version: 0.1.1
Done in 0.08s.

$ git log --oneline
c8211a0 (tag: v0.1.1) v0.1.1
```

Or you just need to commit after changing the version :

```
$ yarn version --patch --no-git-tag-version
yarn version v1.22.5
info Current version: 0.1.0
info New version: 0.1.1
Done in 0.06s.

$ git commit -am "Bump version"

$ git log --oneline
944ee64 (HEAD -> main) Bump version
```

Then you have to push to the repository, see [Cannot push from gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472250/7953086).